# Javascript - cannot dynamically create checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have the following function that dynamically creates a bunch of checkboxes:

```
var drawGroups = function(){
  var groups = document.getElementById("groups"); //groups element is a div
  groups.innerHTML = "";

  //groupList is an array containing strings
  for(var i in groupList){
    var groupName = groupList[i];

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = "checkbox";
    cb.checked = true; //this seems to do nothing
    groups.appendChild(cb);

    groups.innerHTML += groupName + "<br/>"
  }
}
```

Everything I read indicates `cb.checked = true` should check the checkbox, but it doesn't seem to do anything. How can I create the checkboxes in a checked state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `defaultChecked` property:

```js
var groupList = ['foo','bar','baz','biz','boz'];

var drawGroups = function(){
  var groups = document.getElementById("groups"); //groups element is a div
  groups.innerHTML = "";

  //groupList is an array containing strings
  for(var i in groupList){
    var groupName = groupList[i];

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = "checkbox";
    cb.defaultChecked = true;
    groups.appendChild(cb);

    groups.innerHTML += groupName + "<br/>"
  }
}
drawGroups();
```

```html
<div id="groups"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `setAttribute`:

```
cb.setAttribute('checked',  true);
```